# WebBrowser doesn't show my website like it should

Tags: c#, browser

I have a simple `webBrowser` on my `form1` but when I try to load my website, some of the margins do not work. I tested this with chrome and IE, but they displayed my website as they should.

Working in visual studio WFA c#

here's a screenie:[image]

The text in my left list disapeared a little to the left , and my menu bar has a bigger bottom-margin and also my hover effect is floating on my icon o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `WebBrowser` control uses the rendering logic from older versions of IE by default (for "compatibility") and does not follow the current version installed on the computer.

You can override this behaviour and force the control to behave like IE9 by adding the following to your `<head>` element:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

You also need to make sure the `DOCTYPE` is set correctly. This will then enable the kind of rendering behaviour you expect.